# Should I split sentences in a document for Doc2Vec?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am building a Doc2Vec model with 1000 documents using Gensim.
Each document has consisted of several sentences which include multiple words.

Example)

Doc1: [[word1, word2, word3], [word4, word5, word6, word7],[word8, word9, word10]]

Doc2: [[word7, word3, word1, word2], [word1, word5, word6, word10]]

Initially, to train the Doc2Vec, I first split sentences and tag each sentence with the same document tag using  "TaggedDocument". As a result, I got the final training input for Doc2Vec as follows:

TaggedDocument(words=[word1, word2, word3], tags=['Doc1'])

TaggedDocument(words=[word4, word5, word6, word7], tags=['Doc1'])

TaggedDocument(words=[word8, word9, word10], tags=['Doc1'])

TaggedDocument(words=[word7, word3, word1, word2], tags=['Doc2'])

TaggedDocument(words=[word1, word5, word6, word10], tags=['Doc2'])

However, would it be okay to train the model with the document as a whole without splitting sentences?

TaggedDocument(words=[word1, word2, word3,word4, word5, word6, word7,word8, word9, word10], tags=['Doc1'])

TaggedDocument(words=[word4, word5, word6, word7,word1, word5, word6, word10], tags=['Doc2'])

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches are going to be very similar in their effect.

The slight difference is that in PV-DM modes (`dm=1`), or PV-DBOW with added skip-gram training (`dm=0, dbow_words=1`), if you split by sentence, words in different sentences will never be within the same context-window.

For example, your `'Doc1'` words `'word3'` and `'word4'` would never be averaged-together in the same PV-DM context-window-average, nor be used to PV-DBOW skip-gram predict-each-other, if you split by sentences. If you just run the whole doc's words together into a single `TaggedDocument` example, they would interact more, via appearing in shared context-windows.

Whether one or the other is better for your purposes is something you'd have to evaluate in your own analysis - it could depend a lot on the nature of the data & desired similarity results.

But, I can say that your *second* option, all the words in one `TaggedDocument`, is the more common/traditional approach.

(That is, as long as the document is still no more than 10,000 tokens long. If longer, splitting the doc's words into multiple `TaggedDocument` instances, each with the same `tags`, is a common workaround for an internal 10,000-token implementation limit.)

Comment: It helped a lot! Per your recommendation, I decided to take the second option. Also, based on my experiments, I got almost the same results from both options. But, the second one was better. Thank you!